# Why can't I store my orders in Firestore after checkout session

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

When I click checkout button, it redirects to stripe where the user pays the amount from the cart. The payment is successful but the success URL is not working and so the user is redirected to 404 page which I put in my code in case there's an error in payment. Here is my code:

```
app.get('/success', async (req, res) => {
     let { order, session_id } = req.query;
 
     try {
         const session = await stripeGateway.checkout.sessions.retrieve(session_id);
         const customer = await stripeGateway.customers.retrieve(session.customer);
 
         let date = new Date();
 
         let orders_collection = collection(db, "orders");
         let docName = `${customer.email}-order-${date.getTime()}`;
 
         setDoc(doc(orders_collection, docName), JSON.parse(order))
         .then(data => {
             res.redirect('/checkout?payment=done')
         })
     } catch {
         res.redirect("/404")
     }     
})
```

When I tried to `console.log(order)` without the try and catch it shows the order in my terminal but with the try statement which I put firebase code it does not show in the database. Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share how you create the Checkout Session? try using webhook instead of that:
check this firebase function:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/next/firestore-stripe-payments/functions/src/index.ts#L676
Which store in firestore the payment record after the checkout session is completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a problem with either of the `.retrieve()` methods or with the `setDoc` function, then `res.redirect("/404")` will trigger. Make sure there's no issues with `session_id`, `session.customer` (null values) and that the created `docName` exists inside `Firestore`.

Additionally, it may be useful to log the errors in your `try {} catch (e) {}` so you can see what's causing the 404 redirect.